# Stateful Server why not possible in Ruby, PHP, Java, ASP.NET,...?

Tags: php, asp.net, ruby, erlang

In [this video about scaling hundreds of thousands of users](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/1000000-Daily-Users-and-No-Cache) without caching the guy is talking about Erlang Stateful Server. Before they were using Ruby Stateless.

What does a stateful server actually mean? What's the difference between a user's session and that stateful object on the server?

And why would Ruby, PHP, Java or ASP.NET not be able to do the same as Erlang?

Update: in the end the guy said he was obliged to combine Erlang and Ruby so it implies he couldn't do it with Ruby alone.

Comment: "Why would ... not be able to" [citation needed]

Comment: The guy said he was obliged to combine Erlang and Ruby so it implies he couldn't do with Ruby alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't watched the presentation yet, but from the summary it looks like a gaming platform.  Which is quite different than you standard business application.  Your standard business app maintains a  small amount of session local state and that state usually doesn't need to be shared between threads.  Our standard business app rely heavily on databases and caches for sharing business data.

These multi-player gaming systems would require near real-time manipulation of state that needs to be access by many threads.  This is where Erlang excels. It's not that you can't do this in other languages, but you can't do it as as safely or as efficiently.

- Unlike Ruby, there are no locks in Erlang's concurrency model. Erlang uses a message-passing concurrency model (known as the Actor model).  There is no shared mutable memory, so avoid a lot of hard to find programming bugs.
- The Erlang runtime can support hundreds of thousands of light-weight "processes" that can be created and destroyed with very little overhead.
- Erlang's per-process heap make garbage collection quick and allows for near real-time applications.
- Erlang's support for distributed computing excellent, so scaling up by adding hardware is relatively easy.
- Erlang's exception handling and it's supervisory pattern make managing application error easy, even between nodes on the network.

Comment: Thanks. Do these light-weight process allow to create states for Objects if I interpret his "Statefull Server" ?

Comment: Yes, state is maintained within these light-weight processes on the process stack.  It is accessed and updated by sending messages to the process. There are OTP library modules that provide a framework for servers and FSM's.

Comment: I should mention that the JVM language "clojure" also has an interesting approach to concurrency.  Like Erlang, it is a dynamic, functional language that favours immutable data, but instead of maintaining state on the stack of a process, it provides language constructs (called refs) that allow safe, lockless manipulation of state.

Comment: The Erlang runtime can actually support millions of processes, it all depends on how much memory you have available.

Answer (score 2):

A stateful server/app is one that maintains some state between user's requests. Your normal web app is stateless. Each new request is treated as completely new. If you want to persist some information, you use session (normally stored in cookies).

This allows for free scaling of web workers: you just launch as many workers as you need.

Stateful servers/apps allow to perform operations quicker (no need to fetch data from the database each time) and to save on transmitted information (you don't need to pass cookies back and forth), but you pay with reduced scalability. Now you can't just throw incoming request to any vacant worker, you need to direct it to the worker that has user's state.

Surely, you can program in both ways with Ruby. Rails/Sinatra for stateless web apps, EventMachine for stateful daemons.

Comment: "but you pay with reduced scalability": well in this case it's clearly for increase scalablity.

Comment: @user310291: do you have some proof? I have, in the post :)

Comment: What do you mean by "user's state" here ? Because he does oppose user's session with state objects so he doesn't use user's state.

Comment: scalability: that's the very subject of his conference :) "wooga is the second largest developer of social games in the world with more than 5 million daily users and serve more than 10 billion http requests/month".

Comment: My point: if you store state in the server, your users are bound to the server instances where their state is (their session, or state of their world, or whatever). If that server is overwhelmed, it's not that easy to redistribute users to other servers. Hence scalability is reduced.

Comment: This is common knowledge that storing state on server would make things less scalable but his point here is the contrary. I can't explain why because I don't even understand what's he's talking about so my question :) I only know that Erlang is specialized in distributed system so it may be that it is what makes it scalable but I'm not sure.